# all commands are not found after executing "source ~/.bashrc"

Tags: bash, server

I'm working on a SLURM cluster and I needed to add a path to bwa. I followed this instructions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19062-01/sun.mgmt.ctr36/819-5418/gaznb/index.html and after update of my `~/.bashrc` file I used:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The contents of my `~/.bashrc` file now:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=
export PATH=/path/to/bwa                  # added only this line
# User specific aliases and functions
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Now I get the following error for every command:

```
-bash: bwa: command not found
-bash: ls: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
-bash: vim: command not found
-bash: nano: command not found
```

So it looks like before executing above commands some other `~/.bashrc` was used for loading paths and since my file doesn't contain all these paths I can't execute the commands anymore. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

**UPD**:

I managed to fix it. If you're also not a bash/linux guru and you have the same problem, all you need to do is to find `bashrc` and `profile` files with system wide aliases (I found them in `/etc` dir) and then use the same `source` command. That will return everything back to normal. After that you can update your local `~/.bashrc` file to add a path to your command as said in the selected answer.

Comment: You write that you used ".bashrc", but in the title you mention "~/.bashrc". The former will use the bashrc in the current directory, the latter will use the one in your own home directory. Which command did you use? If you were in a different directory there may be differences. And what are the contents of your bashrc (s?)?

Comment: What exactly did you change in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Sorry, I used ~/.bashrc.
The contents of the file:

`# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=
export PATH=/path/to/bwa
# User specific aliases and functions
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: You should *extend* the ``PATH``, not override it.

Comment: OK, thanks to all of you -- I did the wrong thing.
Could you please now help me to fix it?

Comment: You missed the `...:$PATH` part of your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268216/all-commands-are-not-found-after-executing-source-bashrc/57268413#comment101034994_57268216) that you used `PATH=/path/to/bwa`, which will overwrite the complete path.

Instead you need to append the path like `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bwa` to have your old PATH, *plus* the new entry.

Comment: More like `PATH=/path/to/bwa:$PATH` so the new stuff is found first.